# Rewrite Rule for Multiple Languages

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

At the moment the website uses no rewrites, I'm in the process of rewriting both the website and the .htaccess to encorporate this.  It is multilingual, and at the moment the language is changed via a query string (`?lang=en/es/de`).

I would like to format the URL so it reads `http://website.com/en/products/product1`

At the moment the pages are stored as separate files, in other words it's **not** a complete rewrite such as: 
`http://website.com/index.php?page=product1&category=product&lang=en`

Becomes:

`http://website.com/en/products/product1`

The pages are all stored in the root directory, but I have used an individual rule to rewrite the separate files (as it is only a small site).

The problem I'm having is, the regex solutions I have found elsewhere replace the `?lang=en` part and then they place it at the end of the URL.  How could I make it come directly after the domain in the URL as shown above?

Hope this is clear, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Put this code in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# external redirect from actual URL to pretty one
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+index\.php\?page=([^&]*)&category=([^&]*)&lang=([^&\s]*) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%3/products/%1? [R=302,L]

# internal forward from pretty URL to actual one
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ /index.php?page=$3&category=product&lang=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: Note I mentioned that was **not the current URL format**, the pages are stored as individual files like `http://website.com/fluffy-bunny.php` and `http://website.com/small-cat.php`

Comment: You also wrote `I would like to format the URL so it reads http://website.com/en/products/product1` this rule is for that scheme.

Comment: Okay... doesn't appear to work, ideally I should try and get my head around regex.  Would you suggest I 'convert' my website to the whole 'single index page with multiple query strings' format?

Comment: Yes why not, front controller architecture is being used all around the web these days.

Answer (score 0):

I think this hope /* copy and paste below, save the name. htaccess */

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /website.com/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
#ex1:http://website.com/en/products/product1
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z_-]+)/([a-zA-Z_-]+)/([a-zA-Z_-]+)?$ index.php?lang=$1&category=$2&page=$3 [L]
```

/* and in your file php */

```
<!-- #ex1:http://website.com/en/products/product1 -->
<a href="<?php echo "en/products/product1" ?>">Link</a>
```

Comment: Is the fake (SEO) directory **products** while the category wants **product**? Be careful with that!